# Excel: If value in column K matches value in column B, return value from column I but same row as the value matched in column B

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Newbie here and I am working on an inventory system for my small business. I've mad it thus far with lots of Googling but I can't seem to make this one work.
When I scan a barcode it goes in Column K. If the value in K matches with a value in Column B, I want it to return a value from Column H that matches the same row that it matched in Column B. Example: barcode scanned goes in K2, K2 matches value in B12, I want O2 to copy the value from H12.

[image: Spreadsheet Picture]

I have tried this formula but isn't producing what I am looking for:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(B2,$K:K:$K$4500,0)),"",INDEX($H:H:$H$4500,MATCH(B2,$K:K:$K$4500,0)))
```

Comment: Perhaps you should check this bit: "K:K:$K$4500" this bit: "$H:H:$H$4500, and this bit: $K:K:$K$4500" as that seems to be double ranges which seem incorrect.

Comment: when I scan a barcode it makes a value in K and checks for a match in B

Comment: If you want to check a value from column K to see if it exists in column B then you have things the wrong way round. something like match(K2,B:B,0) would return the position of a matching item.

Comment: @SolarMike, you're onto something there! It returns the correct row number. How can I add the Column to the returned row value and extract that info.

Comment: Then use that result to control the index function.

Comment: Thank you @SolarMike, I found this formula to work for me: =IFERROR(INDEX($H$2:$H$4500,MATCH($K3,B:B,0)),"")

Comment: Be carefull, as using b:b counts from row 1 and your reference in col H starts at row 2…

Comment: @SolarMike Happy to report we did a 1st run of the system today, and everything worked perfectly! 4300 items scanned and logged in a fraction of the time it would've taken us before. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

Copy this formula in O1 and copy paste down.

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(K1,$B$1:$B$4500,0)),"",INDEX($H$1:$H$4500,MATCH(K1,$B$1:$B$4500,0),1))
```

Result

[image]

Comment: I copy and pasted but had no results. I did however figure out a formula the yielded the results I was looking for: =IFERROR(INDEX($H$2:$H$4500,MATCH($K3,B:B,0)),"")

Comment: @slughawk Don't you copy it to row 2?